# A composite format string in conjunction with DataTable.Select()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got an array with three elements

```
string[] cat = new string[3] { "XBox360", "PS3", "Wii" };
```

then my I basically compare the array agianst a `DataTable` and do some manipulation under certain conditions. The code that (I didn't write) performs match is this:

```
drResults = dtResults.Select(String.Format("Cat = '{0}' AND Cat_Entries = '{1}'", category, cat[i]));
```

The category (Cat) varialble contains a category numbers and Cat_Entries the elements of the cat array. And so in the code I perform operations if the drResult.Lenght > 0.

What I don't understand is what does the code inside Format() do? I'm looking at [Microsoft's definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) but what throws me off is the "AND". Also are the numbers between curly brackets {} like a sequential index designator that tell the runtime that the category element repalces Zero, and cat[i] replaces One?

All this is of course inside a loop and other code but I don't think it really adds to the question so I left it out.

Comment: The `AND` belongs to `DataTable.Select`(similar to a `WHERE` clause in SQL), the curly braces are placeholder for `string.Format` (as you've already mentioned). So they are not related.

Comment: So basically, `Cat` = `category` and `Cat_Entries` = `cat[i]` and so if there is a match, `dtResults` is 1?

Comment: Seriously people a Downvote? For what?

Comment: @Risho Unexplained downvote is very common in SO; it's actually gotten really bad lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Select method takes a piece of SQL and returns rows that match. In this case you are looking for a row where `Cat field = '<category>' AND the Cat_Entries field = '<cat[i]>'`

The Format function is a better way of creating the string than doing

`"Cat = '" + category + "' AND Cat_Entries = '" + cat[i] + '"` as the latter is harder to read and is probably slower due to having to create several interim strings.

The {0} and {1} are just place holders representing the variables that you provide, ie. 
**category** and **cat[i]**. You can reuse each as many times as you like and in any order,.e.g. it would be valid (albeit stupid) to have

```
String.Format("Cat_Entries = '{1}' AND Cat = '{0}' AND Cat = '{0}'", category, cat[i])
```